# My big integer calculator is not working as planned, can anyone java developers help me out?

Tags: java, calculator, biginteger

I am making a big integer calculator for my comp sci class but some of the things I add together just don't work. Basically to my knowledge it only works with numbers 100 and below (maybe also 999 and below). Specifically what I'm struggling on is that when adding 934 + 168 it always comes out to 10102, instead of 1102. I have made this add up together before, but in the process of trying to fix other problems it doesnt work anymore. If anyone would be able to help me fix my code by telling me where I may have gone wrong, please do. Thanks!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a positive integer.");
    LinkedList a = takeData();
    System.out.println("Please enter another positive integer.");
    LinkedList b = takeData();
    LinkedList<Integer> sum = add(a, b);
    //System.out.println("They add to equal:\t");
    print(sum);
}


public static LinkedList<Integer> add(LinkedList<Integer> a, LinkedList<Integer> b) {
    LinkedList<Integer> sum = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    int decide = 0, s = 0;
    ;
    if (a.size() == b.size())
        decide = 1;
    fillWithZeros(a, b, sum);
    print(a);
    print(b);
    if (decide == 1)
        s = a.size() + 1;
    else
        s = a.size();
    int add = 0, count = 0;

    for (int x = 0; x < s; x++) {
        count = 0;
        add = 0;
        if (x != s && decide == 0 || decide == 1 && x != s - 1)
            add = a.pollLast() + b.pollLast();
        if (sum.size() != 0)
            add += sum.getFirst();
        if (add >= 10) {
            add -= 10;
            //if(sum.size()>0)
            //add+=sum.get(0);
            sum.addFirst(0);
            sum.addFirst(1);
            count++;
            //if(sum.size()>=2) THIS DOES NOTHING
            //add+= sum.get(1);
        }
        System.out.println("\nThe " + x + " digit equals = " + add);
        System.out.println("x = " + x + "\nsum.size = " + sum.size());
           /* if(sum.size()>s-1 && decide==1)
            {
                System.out.println("YOu stopperd here");
            return sum;
        }*/
        if (x != 0) {
            if (sum.size() >= x) {
                add += sum.get(1);


                if (add >= 10) {
                    add -= 10;
                    sum.addFirst(0);
                    sum.addFirst(1);
                    if (sum.size() >= 2)
                        add += sum.get(1);
                    //add-=10;
                    //sum.addFirst(1);
                    sum.set(1, add);
                } else {
                    sum.set(1, add);
                }

                System.out.println(add);

                //sum.set(0,add);
                //}
                //sum.add(x-1,add);
                //sum.add(add);
            } else {
                //add+= sum.get(x-1);
                if (count == 0)
                    sum.set(0, add);
                else
                    sum.set(1, add);
            }
        } else
            sum.addLast(add);
        print(sum);
        if (sum.size() > s - 1 && decide == 1)
            return sum;

    }


    return sum;
}

public static void print(LinkedList<Integer> a) {
    System.out.println("\nSize of LinkList:\t" + a.size());
    for (int x = 1; x <= a.size(); x++)
        System.out.print(a.get(x - 1));
}

public static void fillWithZeros(LinkedList<Integer> a, LinkedList<Integer> b, LinkedList<Integer> c) {
    while (b.size() != a.size()/*||c.size()!=b.size()*/) {
        if (a.size() > b.size())
            b.addFirst(0);
        else if (a.size() < b.size())
            a.addFirst(0);
        /*else
            c.addFirst(0);*/
    }
    /*c.addFirst(0);*/
}

public static LinkedList<Integer> takeData() {
    boolean correctData = true;
    Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
    LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
    do {
        if (correctData == false)
            System.out.println("Please re-enter a correct integer.");
        String n = read.nextLine();
        for (int x = 0; x < n.length(); x++) {
            if (Character.isDigit(n.charAt(x))) {

                int valueOf = n.charAt(x) - 48;
                list.add(valueOf);

            } else {
                correctData = false;
                break;
            }
            correctData = true;
        }

    } while (correctData == false);

    return list;
}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please note that this site is not a debugging service. Copy-pasting large slabs of code into the question and asking us to debug it is off-topic. However, we can help you with *specific* questions about small *parts* of your code (a few lines), ideally accompanied by an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then edit your question to narrow its focus and remove all code not directly relevant. My suggestion is to debug it by stepping through the code execution line by line.

Comment: Does your code really need to be this complicated just to add two integers together?  I've run through it a few times in the debugger, and I can't figure what all it's doing.  I've never seen so much work done on a couple of numbers.  You break them apart into lists, pad with zeros, do stuff I don't understand, and in the end get numbers that aren't right.  What's the point?  I don't get it. - Code that's this crazy and hard to read isn't "correct" even if it gives the right answer.

Comment: is using linked lists of digits to represent your numbers a requirement of the assignment?  There is an easier way... if you're open to it.

Comment: I guess we need to see what the assignment is to understand this.  The straightforward way, using BigInteger, gets this done in 6 lines of code (handling negative numbers too).  - I'm guessing that the assignment is to do the addition digit by digit, but even then, there's way more code here than I can understand a use for.

Comment: Although I completely agree with @Bohemian, you did well to provide a complete example, together with inputs that illustrate it. This is quite unusual for beginners and I congratulate you for it. If you continue to use stackoverflow, please consider if you can shrink your questions so they are more compact while still illustrating the problem. This is sometimes called a minimal, complete, verifiable example or MVCE and is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In fact, the process of doing this often leads you to discover your own bugs.

Answer (score 2):

You should add the numbers the same way you'd do it on paper, i.e. start with the last digits, add them, and carry over a 1 if needed.

To iterate through a list using an [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html), you probably already know you can do it like this:

```java
Iterator<Integer> iter = list.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    int digit = iter.next();
    // use digit here
}
```

A [`ListIterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) can do the same, but it can also iterate backwards:

```java
ListIterator<Integer> iter = list.listIterator(list.size()); // start at end
while (iter.hasPrevious()) {
    int digit = iter.previous(); // iterate backwards
    // use digit here
}
```

The [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) class is excellent for building the result backwards too, because in addition to [`add()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#add-E-), it also has [`addLast()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#addLast-E-) (which does the same thing), as well as [`addFirst()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#addFirst-E-), which we can use to build result starting with the last digit.

Knowing all that then makes it quite simple, something like this:

```java
public static LinkedList<Integer> add(LinkedList<Integer> a, LinkedList<Integer> b) {
    LinkedList<Integer> sum = new LinkedList<>();
    int carry = 0;
    ListIterator<Integer> aIter = a.listIterator(a.size());
    ListIterator<Integer> bIter = b.listIterator(b.size());
    while (carry != 0 || aIter.hasPrevious() || bIter.hasPrevious()) {
        int digitSum = carry;
        if (aIter.hasPrevious())
            digitSum += aIter.previous();
        if (bIter.hasPrevious())
            digitSum += bIter.previous();
        if (digitSum <= 9) {
            carry = 0;
        } else {
            carry = 1;
            digitSum -= 10;
        }
        sum.addFirst(digitSum);
    }
    return sum;
}
```